# EPPlus worksheet.DeleteRow is not deleting the full row

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I call `ws.DeleteRow(1,11,true)` in a process and previously this was working fine.

Now though it deletes the row up until column G

Columns G and H are only having 6 rows deleted instead of the expected 11

What could cause this change? Things have been fine for months with this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the root cause that was preventing deletion of those 5 rows in the 2 columns, all the cells look empty.

As a workaround, I ran `ws.Cells[1,1,11,8].Value = null;` on the line before calling `DeleteRow` and that took care of the issue.